# Alcoholic KOH mechanism with alkyl halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Does alcoholic $\ce{KOH}$ only show $E_2$ mechanism with alkyhalides?

I have studied with two organic chemistry teachers, one told me that there is always $E_2$ mechanism, except in the case of tertiary alkylhalide and the other told me it can be any depending on the substrate with $\alpha$ hydrogens more than 4 or if it has resonance it will show $E_1$.

Which one is true?

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed. Also, please put some more effort into your formatting and spelling. It doesn't have to be perfect but I'm sure you can do better than that.

Comment: This is not a homework ques.   I studied for it on net for an hour but couldn't find anything ..

Comment: A "homework question" is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself. This includes not just questions from actual homework assignments, but also self-study problems, puzzles, etc.

Comment: If u don't know about it then simply say it ..why are you abusing....

Comment: We are not being abusive in any way. We are enacting the policies of the site in a civil manner. And trust me, there are many people on this site who know the answer to this question and many more, which is why it will profit you to show some thought towards you question.

Comment: Then the policy of the site is not up to the mark it shouldn't be like this .......i tell you the proper confusion for this is that i have studied from two organic teachers one told me that there is always e2 mechanism except in the case of tertiary alkyl halide ....And the other told me it can be any depending on the substrate .......with alph hydrogens more than 4 or it is havingresonance  it will show e1..

Comment: If you don't like the policies of our site then feel free to go somewhere else. If you stay here though, you must play by our rules. If you edit your thoughts into the question and tell us what is confusing you then the question will be reopened and you will get an answer.

Comment: @Abhishek - I can see you have edited in your thoughts - I have voted for reopening. Having said that, it would have been done faster if you had followed the rules of the site, as per bon's advice, without the attitude.

Comment: Not sure by what your second teacher said. Can you clarify it by using better grammar or explaining in a more open way?

Comment: He told that if there is formation of stable carbocation which is in conjugation or having alpha hydrogen more than 4 than it will show E1 mechanism...

Answer (score 3):

With a strong base $E2$ will always predominate over $E1$.

Both elimination mechanisms have [a preference for tertiary substrates over secondary substrates over primary substrates](http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/vlu_organik/substitution/sn_e_konkurrenz/sn2_e2_konkurrenz.vlu/Page/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/substitution/sn_e_konkurrenz/a2_3_sn2_e2_substrat/sn2_e2_substrat.vscml.html). This behavior is on contrast with the substitution reactions, where steric factors are important for $S_N2$. Steric factors are less important for the proton transfer necessary for $E2$.

Since $E2$ and $E1$ have the same substrate preference order, you may feel that you cannot decide which is more likely. However, $E2$ is usually faster because $E2$ is bimolecular. Consider the rate laws:

- $\mathrm{rate}_{E2}=k\mathrm{[substrate][base]}$
- $\mathrm{rate}_{E1}=k\mathrm{[substrate]}$

If we make the assumption that the rate constants are of similar magnitude, then increasing the concentration of the base increases the rate of $E2$.

Comment: E2 does have a stereochemical requirement though. The leaving group must be antiperiplanar to the hydrogen.

Comment: Means it will mainly show E2 mechanism....